# SVG world map coords

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Before I venture down one specific route for mapping out an image I am wondering if there is a better method for doing it instead of trying to figure the coords using - (Example below)

```
<map name="myMap">
  <area shape="uk" coords="0,0,82,126" href="" alt="uk">
  <area shape="africa" coords="90,58,3" href="" alt="africa">
  <area shape="northUSA" coords="124,58,8" href="" alt="northUSA">
</map>
```

and typing out the coords?

I have never attempted this before and before I get my butt kicked and told go google it etc I have looked at so many options including:

jVectorMap, DataMaps, JQVMap, CraftMap to name a few....

I have an image made for me, I could slice it up into SVG files for each continent but just really checking it to see what you guys think or have any simple JSFiddle demos which I could use a basis?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

** I must stress that it does not need to be responsive and something relatively straightforward **

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a utility to make image maps in HTML, there are many options. I used one in windows 98 about 15 years ago called GEOHTML. It's still available but hard to find. oh, and it's really old :-)

There are web app options as well like http://www.image-maps.com/

Comment: I would like some control over what is happening, I am wondering perhaps the easiest way to get the coords of an image of a continent as you can imagine the details of the edges? Or the best way to do map around it, the hover state requires a pin also.

Comment: What are you trying to make? HTML <map> or SVG? if you have a bitmap/image as your source, you can use inkscape's "trace bitmap" feature to get an SVG outline. It isn't much of a stretch from there to convert an SVG to a <map>.

Comment: I am just seeking the best way to load in a world map (my own image) and change the hover state of each continent so when you hover Europe for example the continent highlights and adds a stroke around the continent and shows a tooltip. Sounds more complicated than it is but it does not need to be responsive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve with the map, but here's an idea (provided it's covered by the *Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International License*):

Go [here](http://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=world) and download the SVG file for the world (either low detail or high detail, depending on your needs). It's a nicely formatted SVG with IDs and titles for each country.

If you want to make it interactive, you can attach a click event to each `<path>` element in the SVG.

Comment: I am required to use the image I have been provided with. I have looked at this particular option 'amcharts' but I have all the continents as individual SVG files which need positioning and adding a hover state change. It isn't anything too over the top but wanting to find the most sensible option.

Comment: Does your SVG include an identifier for each country (ie. an `id` or `class`)?  If not, can you not add one?  Then you can still use Dan's suggestion.

Comment: I can add an id or class without a problem. Would this allow me swap the image of the country on hover?